# How to get 2nd Saturday of Last Month in Where Clause

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automation

I am trying to setup an automation which will run daily and get the data from Capture DE which have a field name 'LastCapture' date type. The data is loaded on 2nd Saturday of each month.

I am trying to figure out how do I get only last month 2nd Saturday data in WHERE CLAUSE. So in this example the last data was loaded on 7/8/2023.

I used the below command in Where Clause, but this will not going to work based on some months have 30 days some have 31 and 28. I think I need to use DATEPART somehow?

```
WHERE p.LastCapture >= DATEADD(day,-31, GETDATE()))
```

The challenge is, Today is 8/8/23 so when I run the query Today through 8/11/23 it should get data from 7/8 while on 8/12 we will get a new data. Thus from 8/12/23 through 9/8/23 the query should be getting only 8/12/23 data.

Any help or suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a purely SQL answer to the question, you would need something along these lines:

```
WHERE p.LastCapture >= DATEADD(DAY,14-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE()))),CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE()))))
```

Basically, figure out what day of the week the first day of last month was (Sunday is day 1), subtract that number from 14 and add the resulting days to the first of last month.

This is pretty dense stuff and awkward to work with. It's also quite brittle... Suppose your wanted to change the cadence of extracts or you needed to rerun your extract after a failure.

I'd recommend a different approach where you add a "DateExtracted" field to your capture table that's nullable. You first run a query to identify unextracted records and output them to flat file, so:

```
WHERE p.DateExtracted IS NULL
```

Then run a seperate query to update your capture table to set the DateExtracted to the current date for records where the DateExtracted is null.

Comment: Thanks Macca. Currently my workaround is I actually have a another table 'UPDATES' and using Updates table for suppression. So whenever eligible peoples inject into Sendable DE they also get added onto Update Table. Problem is when I am using where clause which I mentioned above then sometime data gets overlap but I know updates table suppress those overlap data because they are already on that table.
I was looking for any other logic which is more accurate rather than workaround sort of thing :)